# Failed to Set MokListRT: Invallid Parameter every time I boot up my laptop

Tags: boot, moklistrt

Why do I get this black screen when booting my laptop?

[image]

```
Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter  
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this because you need to replace a file. Do this:

```
sudo su -
cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi
```

After doing this, restart your Mac. The problem will be gone.